# I need to rank the below given data

Tags: sql, db2

```
effective_date  termination_date  rank
1/1/2015        1/31/2015         1
2/1/2015        2/28/2015         1
3/3/2015        3/31/2015         2
4/1/2015        4/30/2015         2
```

Basically when there is a gap between the `previous termination_date` and the `current effective_date` I need to assign a new rank/value and continue the rank/value until I find a new gap in the between the `current effective_date` and previous `termination_date`.

Also, stored procedures are not allowed to be used. Kindly tell me the way to achieve this with DB2 queries

Comment: How about adding all other **RDBMS** tags as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions.  The following uses `lag()` to identify where continuous periods start.  It then cumulatively sums this flag to identify each group:

```
select t.*, sum(IsStart) over (order by effective_date)
from (select t.*,
             (case when lag(termination_date) + 1 days >= effective_date
                   then 0 else 1
              end) as IsStart
      from t
     ) t;
```